# Python condition with regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a file with those data :

```
PAS_BEGIN_0009999
    T71_MANUFACTURER_4=98
    T71_COLOR_ID_7=000
    T71_OS_7=08
PAS_END_0009999

PAS_BEGIN_0009996
    T72_VAS_SERVICE_IDENTIFIER_6=
    T72_ORDER_NB_7=0003
    T72_TECHNOLOGY_7=01
PAS_END_0009996

TPV_BEGIN
    PAS_20819001=3600000 
TPV_END
```

How can I simply isolate content between`PAS_BEGIN_0009996` and `PAS_BEGIN_0009996`

Here is a link for the example : https://regexr.com/3vmeq

It finds something, but my python code doesn't find anything..

```
if re.match("PAS_BEGIN_0009999([\S\s]*)PAS_END_0009999", line):
    data.append(line)
    print(line)
```

Can anyone help me on this ? Thanks

Comment: `re.match` only searches at the start of the string. Use `re.search`. Also, change `[\S\s]*` to `[\S\s]*?`

Comment: I don't think my problem is only with search or match. By changing to search, it doesn't change the result

Comment: A, yes, a common issue: you are reading line by line. Use `with open(filepath, "r") as f: contents = f.read()`. Search inside `contents`.

Comment: I did this `if re.search("PAS_BEGIN_0009999[\S\s]*PAS_END_0009999", contents): data.append(contents)` but it adds all my file,looks like it doesn't understand my regex

Comment: No, `m = re.search(....)`, then `if m:`, then `data.append(m.group())`. Or use `data = re.findall(regex, contents)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading a text file line by line, but your expected match is located on several lines. You need to read the whole file into a variable, then run a regex like yours, or, better, a pattern like `a.*?b` with `re.DOTALL` option so that `.` could match line break chars.

So, you may use something like

```
import re
fpath = 'your_file_path.txt'
data = ''
pattern=r'PAS_BEGIN_0009999(.*?)PAS_END_0009999'
with open(filepath, "r") as f:
    contents = f.read()
    m = re.search(pattern, contents)
    if m:
        data = m.group(1) # or `.group() if you need to include PAS_BEGIN_0009999 and PAS_END_0009999
```

If you need to find multiple occurrences, replace the `re.search` part (all lines after `contents`) with

```
data = re.findall(pattern, contents)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5axJWi/1)

Comment: Thanks, with the comment from my post, you solved a part of my problem ;)